# How to save attendance of student everyday using JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable

Hello everyone i want to store the attendance of student into the database, i can populate the stored name of user to JTable and current date but i want to save JTextfield values into the database as well new records should be save to database as next day.[image]

I am using rs2xml to populate jtabel as well sqlite manager(firefox addon) regarding database.

code :

```
private void update_table(){
try{
Connection con=connectdatabse.ConnecrDb;
String sql = "select * from studentinfo";
PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql); 
ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
TableStudent.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));//TableStudent is variable of JTable
}
catch(Exception e){
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
```

}

Comment: please show the code of what you have tried and where there is an error.  if there is no error, or you have not tried anything, do so and then come back to us.  SO is not a place for others to write your code for you, it is a place for others to help you fix broken code.

Comment: Dude i have code for all this stuff i will edit this post, fine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### GUI Design

You don't need to have the current date in the JTable.  You can put it in a JLabel above the JTable.

It would be a better user experience (ux) if you put the present / absent boolean in the JTable as a JCheckBox before the name.  This makes your GUI look more like a paper roll book.

I wish I could draw you a picture of the GUI I have in mind.  I hope my description helps.

### Database Design

I would suggest a relational database with the following tables.

```
Student
-------
Student ID
Student Last Name
Student First Name
...
```

Student ID is an auto-incrementing integer defined as the primary (clustering) key of the table.

```
School Date
-----------
School Date
```

This table has a row for each day that's a part of the school year.  This way, your code doesn't have to worry about weekends or school holidays.  If the current date is in the table, it's a school day.

You have to create and load this table before the school year or semester starts.

School Date descending is the primary (clustering) key for the table.

```
Attendance
----------
Attendance ID
School Date
Student ID
Present / Absent
```

Attendance ID is an auto-incrementing integer defined as the primary (clustering) key of the table.

Student ID is a foreign key that points back to the Student table and defines which student was present / absent.

I hope that this is enough information to get you started.

Comment: Thank you Gilbert, you wont believe but all things are working fine now as per your suggestion I've created database design and guess what :D data is fetched by the SQL and even retrieving back :D...Thank you very much..!!!

Comment: @Deepak S. Gavkar: You're welcome.  It's great to be able to give a few hints to help someone get going.

Answer (score 1):

Which database system do you use? Is a database really needed or may a file be enough? Looks like an learning / education task.

So you can try to store Java objects with a technique called **serialization**. Or you could write a **textfile** (e.g. a **CSV-File**). If you want to store the data into a **database** you should have a look at **JDBC**.

That are three ways to store data with terms for an internet search, with which can start your journey.

Good luck.

Comment: I am using sql databse behind all this. i want to store the attendance on regular basis

Comment: So please post your code and we might help you (edit your initial question). What is already working? Did you retrieve the values displayed in the screenshot already from the database?